# Issues with Flyway(6.5.7) and Spring Boot 2.5.x?

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

We are using Flyway 6.5.7 and we are trying to upgrade from Spring Boot 2.4.13 to Spring Boot 2.5.x. Application is built with Gradle 7.2.

Before the Spring Boot upgrade everything works fine, but after it bean creation fails with this error when starting the application:

```
Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name must not be null", "level":"WARN","thread":"main","logClass":"o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext","logMethod":"refresh"}
```

If we disable Flyway the application starts fine with Spring Boot 2.5.x.

And if we switch back to a Spring Boot version earlier than 2.5.x and activate Flyway again it works fine...

So whats up with Flyway and Spring Boot 2.5.x?

Comment: What's the complete stack trace, ideally not in JSON, of the failure?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.5 itself uses Flyway 7.7.3, so I suspect your current flyway version is too old to be used with Spring Boot 2.5. I would suggest to upgrade (and not to manually manage your flyway dependencies but rather use the version from spring Boot).

Comment: @M.Deinum: But Flyway 7.x and above are not "community" editions? If we remove the Flyway version from the build file it uses version 7.1.1 and that requires a license: "Flyway Teams Edition or Sybase ASE upgrade required: Sybase ASE 16.0 is no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition, but still supported by Flyway Teams Edition"

Comment: Then don't upgrade spring. Flyway is commercial for certain databases, apaprently the one you are using, so either pay for a license (and be able to use new features) or don't ugprade and stick with an old Spring Boot version.

Comment: @M.Deinum Tell that to Snyk :)

Comment: Well that ultimatly will also tell you to upgrade Flyway. So either don't upgrade, upgrade and pay for it (if it is useful to you why not) or stop using Flyway and switch to liquibase for instance).

Comment: It looks like the newer version has more strict requirements.  May I suggest that you use a debugger to look at the code leading to the exception?  In particular, try to find out if there is a place where you could provide the required `Name` value.