# Flyway configuration in Spring Boot throws ClassCastException upgrading to Spring Boot 2.5

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I have a Spring Boot application with Flyway. I am currently using Spring Boot 2.4 and Flyway configuration is working. When I upgrade to Spring Boot 2.5 I have a problem.

When I go from Spring Boot 2.4.13 to 2.5.0 I get the following exception:

```
Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource cannot be cast to org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource
```

This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70020399/issues-with-flyway6-5-7-and-spring-boot-2-5-x) seems related but the error message is different.

The version of Flyway I am using is 7.10.0 also different from the linked ticket.

We are using separate credentials for Flyway and the Spring Boot 2.5 Release Notes says that this is not longer supported, so I think that the issue is related with that.

Comment: Are you using a different Flyway version than the one provided by the Spring Boot parent?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.5 parent uses flyway 7.7 version. I have also tested with that version and the result is the same.

Comment: can you please show your pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not using `spring.flyway.url` property.

The issue got fixed adding the property like this to application.properties file:

`spring.flyway.url=${spring.datasource.url}`